# arm-linux-androideabi-ar: Command not found in NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, android-ndk

Downloaded NDK file from this (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) link for Linux computer.
arm-linux-androideabi-ar file is not available in downloaded NDK file.

Getting below compilation application in my NDK application.

android-ndk-r25/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar: Command not found

I need to do anything after downloading NDK file.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved. I have downloaded "android-ndk-r21e" & in this version "arm-linux-androideabi-ar" file is available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GNU ar was [deprecated in r22](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r22) and [removed in r23](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r23). Always read changelogs when you upgrade. They tell you this sort of thing.

You should migrate to `llvm-ar`. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems